# How to increase SSRS bandwidth/download limit in SQL Server 2008R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I got a problem in SQL Server 2008R2 SSRS

When I call 1 million data for Report from SSRS Server   , and my URL is like below
http: // 172.--.--.--/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fMyReportProject%2fStoreSales&rs:Command=Render&rs:format=PDF&NumberOfRows=1000000

But When I increase my client PC bandwidth to 50 Mbps , it downloads the PDF at 320 KBps on average
and when the bandwidth is 100 Mbps on my client PC , it also downloads on same speed .
But when I set the Client PC bandwidth limit 0.5Mbps , it downloads on a small speed .
that means , SSRS server has a highest level limitation ,though I increase the bandwidth to a huge level , it can not provide that much download speed.

Is there any way that I can increase the download speed ? or Is there any configuration on SQL Server / SSRS ?

When I call the PDF from my Client PC browser , then I can see like below lines in SQL Server Profiler

exec ReadChunkSegment @ChunkId='B1DD6175-1A6E-E311-839B-005056C00008',@IsPermanent=0,@SegmentId='24DE6175-1A6E-E311-839B-005056C00008',@DataIndex=0,@Length=15730

That means , its taking data in chunk . and is there any way to increase this param  @Length value ?

Any good suggestion will be highly appreciated...

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the upload speed on your server ???

Comment: Server is on our Local Network . its on our LAN . Not production . And I also tested on my local PC (client + Server on same PC) , It shows the same thing . I assume - SQL SERVER 2008R2 / SSRS has any limitation / configuration to process the PDF with 1 million rows and send it back to client . In client PC , I get same download speed 300 KB/s on average with 50 Mb/s and 100 Mb/s .